# fopen is not working on my server

Tags: php

It works perfectly on localhost with Xampp, but when I try it on my server (host-ed.net), fopen can't open any url, it only works for files without http.

```
<?php
$file="http://www.google.es";
$gestor = fopen($file, "r") or die ("Nothing");
?>
```

In my server with this code shows Nothing. Can be anything on the php.ini ?

EDIT: In the php.ini: allow_url_fopen = On

EDIT: It's solved. My server had it disabled, but now it's enabled. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: What, specifically, did your server have disabled, and what steps did you take to enable it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> fopen can't open any url

Check the value of the [`allow_url_fopen` php.ini setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen):

```
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));
```

It's probably false.  You'll need to speak to your web host, or try another method.  Mabye [CURL](http://php.net/curl) is enabled?

You should also check your [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/error_reporting) and [`display_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) values.  PHP should have complained loudly about being unable to open the URL.  You'll want to turn both of them all the way up while developing code, so you can understand what goes wrong easier.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write it...it's ok. allow_url_fopen = On

Comment: In that case, you'll want to check your error reporting level and make sure errors can be displayed.  PHP can then tell you what's actually going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Search for `allow-url-fopen` in your PHP.ini.

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: If you can't find it in your php.ini and are using PHP-FPM, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43539849/729324

Answer (score 2):

The permission for opening urls with `fopen` is controlled by the [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) setting [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen). You can see your current setting using [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) which will dump an html doc containing all your server settings.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a free hosting account? Most hosting services limit outgoing connection for free accounts to prevent abuse. Try this:

```
$fp = fsockopen("some.alive.site", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "Everything is OK";
    fclose($fp);
}
```

If you'll see an error message - you are not allowed to make outgoing connections.

Answer (score 0):

As http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php states,

> If filename is of the form "scheme://...", it is assumed to be a URL and PHP will search for a protocol handler (also known as a wrapper) for that scheme. If no wrappers for that protocol are registered, PHP will emit a notice to help you track potential problems in your script and then continue as though filename specifies a regular file.

I would therefore assume that there is no registered wrapped for url's, and php is treating that as a regular filename, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP-FPM, also check the configuration files in `pool.d/`. PHP-FPM pools can override php settings by using `php_admin_flag`, `php_admin_value`, `php_flag` or `php_value`. (We encountered this on a Ubuntu 16 vps)