# site map script : unexcuted php codes on the file_get_contents

Tags: php

hi i'm trying to create a site map for my website 
(and i don't want to use any application or ready to use code)

here is how my code works .
first it scans the root directory for files and puts them in a array .
then it loops trough array and get contents of that file and then it'll parse the contents for links (a tags)

scaning the directory

```
public function scan($directory)
{
        $dir = dir($directory);
        while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false) {
       $type  = ($this->is_directory($directory.$file)) ? 'dir' : 'link' ;
           $this->files[] =  array('address'=>$directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file , 'type'=>$type); 
       }
       sort($this->files);    
       $dir->close();      
}
```

looping trough files and parsing their contents

```
 public function get_links(){
         foreach($this->files as $f )
         {
             if($f['type']  == 'link' )
             { 
                    $contents =  file_get_contents($f['address']);
                    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
                    $DOM->loadHTML($contents);
                    $a = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');
                    foreach($a as $link){
                        $this->links[] =  $link->getAttribute('href');
                    }

             }
         }
     }
```

now the problem is when i get the contents of a file in the second pice of code , the php code in that file is not executed  . 
so i may get something like :

```
www.site.com/<?php echo $a; ?>.html
or
www.site.com/news.php?id=<?php echo $a; ?>
```

how can i solve this ? 
should i go for curl ? but that wouldn't work with files and it would only works with url address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how complicated your php files are. If you're using MVC or a framework, it may not be as simple as loading the file contents. If you've got simple php files (a few stand-alone pages with a few classes included), you can do:

```
ob_start();
include($f['address']);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to go with curl. `file_get_contents()` reads the file on your hard-disk byte by byte. Meaning it will read your code and not execute it.

For clarification: You don't strictly have to use cURL, but anything that let's you request pages via your webserver and not from the filesystem. So if your server supports it you could do `file_get_contents('http://example.org')`, however you won't get around using URLs.

Comment: This is not actually true, you can use file_get_contents() to get remote content like `http://localhost/mysite/folder/file.php`, so there is no reason to go for cURL especially if content is local

Comment: Yes that's true if ALLOW_URL_FOPEN? is set. However my point was not strictly that is has to be cURL but that he has to use URL's and request the files from his webserver.

Comment: yeah, allow_url_fopen needs to be set.

Answer (score 1):

You have to play ping-pong with your web server and access the file using an url like 
http: //mysite.com/myfile.php

There are various methods of getting the http content. 
See for example here:
[fopen is not working on my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038694/fopen-is-not-working-on-my-server)