# Converting fopen to curl using while loop

Tags: php, curl, while-loop

Hi all I created a function (PHP) that basically opens a text file with a list of dates each date on it's own line. I then use a while look to go through each line of the file to see if a date listed matches todays or if theres no match get the next date nearest to todays. Problem is the host I put the function on doesnt support fopen so I need to convert it to curl. I've looked at some examples but can only find a way to get the contents using curl not check line by line could you help me convert this to curl? Here is my code:

```
function service_dates() {

$file_path .= "/dates.txt"; 
$handle = fopen($file_path, "r");

if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $new_time = strtotime( $line );
        $time_now = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", gmmktime()));

        if ($time_now == $new_time) {
            $next_date = date("D, jS M", $new_time);
            $status = "Operating a Service Today!";
            $statusid = 1;
            $returnstatus = array($status, $next_date, $statusid);
            return $returnstatus;           
        }

        if ($time_now <= $new_time) {
            $next_date = date("D, jS M", $new_time);
            $status = "Closed Today";
            $statusid = 2;
            $returnstatus = array($status, $next_date, $statusid);

            return $returnstatus;               
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
} 
 else {
    echo "error";
  } 

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work with `fopen`? How exactly does the server not support it? That's a builtin/core function. -- Asking to get your code rewritten is entirely unclear and pointless. `curl` doesn't deal with local files much.

Comment: @mario basically I wrote that and tested it locally all worked fine but I uploaded it to the server and it wouldnt work. So I looked at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038694/fopen-is-not-working-on-my-server which I found fopen is disabled. The top answer on that suggested curl so I have been looking at that but can't figure out how to use curl in a loop for each line.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an actual error message. And `allow_url_fopen` has **nothing** to do with opening local files.

Comment: @mario Sorted it now thanks to the guy below. I did not realise allow_url_fopen had nothing to do with fopen not running. Also I wasn't seeing any errors at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [explode](http://php.net/explode) to split the data into individual lines and iterate through the resulting array using a foreach loop:

```
foreach(explode("\n", $data_from_curl) as $line){
    ...
}
```

(replace "\n" by "\r\n" if your file uses windows line break)

Comment: Perfect thanks just what I was after just wasn't sure what way I should get each line from the curl result and this worked perfectly :)