# How can I debug a connection timeout on PHP readfile to Amazon Cloudfront?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, readfile

Until today, I used PHP's `readfile()` function to output an image on S3, through CloudFront.

Now, I get a timeout on this function. On pasting the same URL in a browser, it just works and the image gets displayed.

To be clear: **it worked until today, and I don't recall altering PHP's config**.
`phpinfo()` says:

[image]

So my question is really: how do I debug this problem?

Comment: Start by posting some code.

Comment: See [the manua](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)l: "A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled." More info on the duplicate I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check a few smaller bits to see if we can isolate this:

1. Ensure `allow_url_fopen` [is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9038716/3000068).
2. Ensure DNS requests can be resolved.
3. Ensure IPv4 connections work properly.*
4. Ensure IPv6 connections work properly.*
5. Attempt the entire thing with `file_get_contents()`, which uses the same fopen wrappers.

*Note that it's important to check *both* of these. I've had experiences in the past where different system level tools that PHP makes use of use different versions of IP. It's rather confusing with `curl_*` works fine, but `file_get_contents()` doesn't.

Here's a script that checks each of these:

```
<?php
//Not relevant - Formatting for web browsers...
if (php_sapi_name() !== "cli") {
    echo "<pre>";
}

//Ensure PHP is configured correctly.
$allowUrlFopen = ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
if($allowUrlFopen){
    echo "Success: allow_url_fopen is enabled.\n";
} else {
    echo "FAILURE: allow_url_fopen is disabled.\n";
}

//Check that DNS is working.
$dns = dns_get_record("www.google.com");
if($dns){
    echo "Success: DNS has resolved.\n";
} else {
    echo "FAILURE: DNS did not resolve.\n";
}

//A Google webserver (IPv4). the IP provided was listed in $dns.;
$ipv4 = curl_init("http://216.58.217.36");
curl_setopt($ipv4, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ipv4);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ipv4, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
//The server responded at all, what it responded with isn't important.
if($statusCode >= 100){
    echo "Success: Accessing Google's IPv4 web server succeeded.\n";
} else {
    echo "FAILURE: Accessing Google's IPv4 web server failed.\n";
}

//A Google webserver (IPv6). The IP provided was listed in $dns.;
$ipv6 = curl_init("http://2607:f8b0:400f:803::2004");
curl_setopt($ipv6, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ipv6);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ipv6, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($statusCode >= 100){
    echo "Success: Accessing Google's IPv6 web server succeeded.\n";
} else {
    echo "FAILURE: Accessing Google's IPv6 web server failed.\n";
}

//Fetch remote data via fopen url wrappers (file_get_contents utilizies them).
$file = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
$characters = strlen($file);
if($characters){
    echo "Success: using fopen wrappers to fetch remote data via a URL succeeded.\n";
} else {
    echo "FAILURE: using fopen wrappers to fetch remote data via a URL failure.\n";
}

if (php_sapi_name() !== "cli") {
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Be sure to investigate any failures with lower level system tools. I've gotten stuck on an issue similar to this in where *all* IPv6 on my operating system was timing out. Disabling IPv6 system wide fixed it.

Comment: So, this result comes out:
Success: allow_url_fopen is enabled.
Success: DNS has resolved.
Success: Accessing Google's IPv4 web server succeeded.
FAILURE: Accessing Google's IPv6 web server failed.
Success: using fopen wrappers to fetch remote data via a URL succeeded.

How do I disabled IPv6 system wide?

Comment: That's going to depend on your OS. You'll have to search around a bit. I'm not comfortable adding that level of detail on this answer.

Comment: Well, thanks for your elaborate answer anyway! I will investigate the IPv6 failure tomorrow, and started using curl where readfile failed.

Comment: Actually. It's a bit odd that the `file_get_contents()` check passed but the usage in question failed - IPv6 very well might not be the issue. Is it possible you're trying to access an **https** url? I didn't address that here, but there could be something with OpenSSL. I'll have to add some more checks for that.

Comment: Sorry, it's https indeed!